# Get Rendered HTML from a page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

Hello I have a html page (twitter.html) with the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getParameterByName(name)
            {
              name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
              var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
              var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
              var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
              if(results == null)
                return "";
              else
                return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }
            var TwitterCount = getParameterByName('TwitterCount');
            var TwitterHandleName = getParameterByName('TwitterHandleName');
            new TWTR.Widget({
                version: 2,
                type: 'profile',
                rpp: TwitterCount,
                interval: 30000,
                width: 272,
                height: 'auto',
                theme: {
                    shell: {
                        background: '#ffffff',
                        color: '#000000'
                    },
                    tweets: {
                        background: '#ffffff',
                        color: '#005A8C',
                        links: '#000000'
                    }
                },
                features: {
                    scrollbar: false,
                    loop: false,
                    live: false,
                    behavior: 'all'
                }
            }).render().setUser(TwitterHandleName).start();
        </script>
```

If I access the page

```
http://localhost/twitter.html?TwitterHandleName=billgates&TwitterCount=3
```

I am able to see the last 3 tweets.

What I want is to do an http posting on this page from my aspx page. Below code returns only the script tags etc instead of rendered html. My question is how to get the rendered html of a page?

```
HttpWebRequest loHttp = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/twitter.html?TwitterHandleName=billgates&TwitterCount=3);
            loHttp.Timeout = 30000;    
            loHttp.UserAgent = "Twitter";
            HttpWebResponse loWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loHttp.GetResponse();
            //Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);  // Windows default Code Page

            StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(loWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

            string htmlCode = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

            loWebResponse.Close();
            loResponseStream.Close();
```

Comment: Difficult, very Difficult ! You need to run the javascript as you are a web-browser, generate the DOM, and read it as html.

Comment: Give a try to the http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 1):

I understand it's using a prebuilt javascript widget, but could you move it server-side using a twitter wrapper like https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp (available from NuGet) or http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/?

Comment: yes it will be much easier to just get the tweets from the server

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open that  url into frame on your web page and get html from them using javascript.